# My circuit doesn't respond properly to the duty cycle

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

my circuit is shown on the picture. the problem is the output of the mosfet does't work as desired. For example, If I use Vin=100V and the duty cycle is 50%, the output is Vout=19V. 
Anyway, the output is not even near to the desired value.
can you help, please?
[image]

Comment: Am I seeing a buck converter without feedback ?

Comment: Can you specify at least your inductor? I'm wondering if you can handle the switching losses if you really switch with 20MHz

Comment: @Humpawumpa  F=20KHz, the inductor L=200mH

Comment: @Puffafish I wanna test my modified MPPT algorithm on a solar converter. the first stept to make the circuit and see if it works. I thought if Vin=100V and the duty cycle is 50%, so Vout should be =50V, doesn't it?

Comment: Is that supposed to be an N-channel MOSFET? Your symbol is inconsistent. How exactly are your "driver" and its power supplies connected to the rest of the circuit? There's far too little information here for us to even speculate about what might be going wrong.

Comment: Rotate your diagram if you want to show some respect.

Comment: You cannot use and an Nch FET on a high side switch since Vgs must be greater than input 100V so use a proper driver with a Pch FET

Comment: @RAMZI if you read the second paragraph in my answer I state that it does not.

Comment: Is HCPL-3120 meant to be the pn of the driver? That part isn't going to produce an output voltage any higher than the VCC you supply it.

Answer (score 2):

Your circuit responds exactly how it should. Otherwise physics is wrong.

What you've got there is a buck converter with no feedback. So the output voltage will be lower that input voltage, how much lower depends on the duty cycle and the impedance of the load and the power source.

There are various ways you can get what you want out of this:
- Have feed back and control the duty cycle accordingly to get the desired Vout
- Match the load, source and duty cycle to get your desired Vout

If you put in feedback, then happy days. The duty cycle will correct (within operating limits) to keep the voltage constant. If you don't put in feedback, any change in the source or load will change the Vout.

To assist any more, I would want to know a lot more about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @The Photon , Yes, I'm using the HCPL3120 as a driver. what's wrong with that?

Comment: I appreciate your help. but, the first step is to check if the ckt respond the duty cycle. Maybe I don't get exactly what you mean, but I want if Vin=60V and the duty cycle is 20%, Vout should be = 12V. what's wrong with this logic? thank you

Comment: @RAMZI this is a pretty basic electronics question. You need to do some research about how DCDC converters work, and how FETs turn on. Think about the FET as a switch, when it is closed there is 0V across the FET, so VOUT will be VIN. The capacitor is now VIN, when you turn off the FET, why would the voltage on the capacitor go down?